# Display Error Message For Select If Expand Then Closed Without Selection Made In JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `select` and i'm after displaying an error message as soon as the user expands the `select` and closes it without making a selection but i cant figure how to do this.

I have it validating `on.change` if the `val` matches the default as shown below

**Working JQuery When An Option Is Selected**

```
$('#orderPosition').change(
        function () {
            if ($('#orderPosition').val() == 'orderPositionDefault') {
                $('#orderErrorMessage').show();
                $('#orderPosition').focus();
                $('#orderPosition').css("background-color", "lightcoral");
            } else {
                $('#orderErrorMessage').hide();                    
                $('#orderPosition').css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        }
    );
```

I have tried the following

```
$('#orderPosition').on('click', function () {    
        // var isDirty = !this.options[this.selectedIndex].defaultSelected;
        var changed = $(this).val() != $(this).data('orderPositionDefault');
        alert(changed ? 'changed' : 'not changed');

        if (changed) {
            $('#orderErrorMessage').show();
        } else {
            $('#orderErrorMessage').hide(); 
        }
    });
```

But the issue with the above is as soon as i click in the `select` the error message is displayed, i need it to be displayed of the user clicks in it and closes it straight away without making a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **blur** event for executing code when focus leaves on an input field.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    //change things here 
}).on('blur', function() {
    //when select is no longer in focus here
});
```

> Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onblur.asp

Comment: This works for one `select` but if i add the same code to my second `select` it doesn't work as i added and `alert` in the `blur` and as soon as i click out the first drop down the alert never goes away and seems to be stuck in a loop so when i do the same on the next `select` it doesn't care about it at all. any help on the above

Comment: I don't get the problem really. Could you recreate the problem in a js fiddle or code pen?